# Sequential File Number Generation

Tags: java, android, file, sequence

Hi  I have a tricky problem that seems simple but it has been teasing my brain ever since I started it.

My app allows the user to enter a Product Number and an image Number. The app can take more than one image of one product.

When saving the images to gallery I would like to add a sequential file number to it so that I know which images are linked to which product.

Here is the format in which the file will be saved:

```
String fname = TypeNo + "(" + ImageNo + ")" + sequentialNumber + ".jpg";
```

For example,

```
Type No = Test1;
ImageNo = 1;
sequentialNumber = 1;
fname = Test1(1)1;
```

When the user saves this one, they go back to the data entry activity and If they keep the same TypeNo/ProductCode then the sequentialNo should stay the same for the next save.

If the user enters a different TypeNo/ProductNo then the sequentialNo will increment.

Here is the code I have tried so far which doesn't increment correctly when a new TypeNo is entered:

```
private void saveImageToExternalStorage(Bitmap bitmap_view) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/Digital_Images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname = TypeNo + "(" + ImageNo + ")" + sequentialNumber + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap_view.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
    // immediately available to the user.
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    String lastUsedTypeNo = TypeNo;
    editor.putString("TypeNo", lastUsedTypeNo);
    editor.putInt("sequentialNum", sequentialNumber);
    editor.apply();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String TypeNoRetrieved = sharedPreferences.getString("TypeNo", null);
    int SQNumRetrieved = sharedPreferences.getInt("sequentialNum", 1);

    if (TypeNoRetrieved != null || SQNumRetrieved != 0) {
        if (TypeNoRetrieved == lastUsedTypeNo ) {
            sequentialNumber = SQNumRetrieved;
        } else {
            sequentialNumber++;
        }
    }

}
```

Anyone able to solve this puzzle for me?